# How to execute string as code on page load c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wan to execute code on page load event from string.

Example

```
 string code = "divmainmenu.Style["display"] = "block";"

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if(!IsPostBack)
                    { 
                       Execute(code);

                     }
                }
```

Comment: are you talking about dropping javascript for the client to execute, or are you talking about running server-side C# ?

Comment: Sir, i wan to run server side c#.

Comment: in that case, the answer is mostly "don't". There *are* some direct scripting APIs, but that isn't a common scenario, and it is fraught with security concerns. Is there any reason you can't just *code the code you want*?

Comment: Yes you are right thanks for your valuable reply. java script instead of c# code but there is some other issue when i call java scrip code behind c# in content page its not working. can you help with below code.

Comment: its working without content page, but i need it with content page.  thank you sir.

Comment: `foreach (string showmenu in listmainmenu){string str = "<script type='text/javascript'> document.getElementById('<%= Page.Master.FindControl(\"forms\").FindControl(\"" + showmenu.ToString() + "\").ClientID %>').style.display = \"Block\";</script>"; Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myscript"+showmenu, str, false);}`